# Display error messages in rails simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, simple-form

I am new to rails and was wondering if someone could show me some light...

I have a simple form with couple of input fields and need to display field validation messages below the field name. Is there is a straightforward way to say display errors below??? or do i have to check for each field error message and create a span tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify in your `simple_form.rb` initializer file with which tag your error message will be wrapped:

```
b.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => :span, :class => :error }
```

Also you can disable default error component on the input and print it by yourself like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, error: false %>
  <%= f.error :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and style your error message like you want.